# Get legend or title using LaTeX in R

Tags: r, plot, legend

I want to do a plot, with 'n' as a legend (or the main title) with the input of n. At the moment, the integers works fine. But I want to make the fractions work too, for example like the 1/3 and -1/3, preferably using LaTeX notation.

Here is my code:

```
mydraw <- function(n,lb=-pi,up= pi){

    dat<- data.frame(t=seq(lb,up, by=0.001) )

    xhrt <- function(t) cos(t) - cos(n*t)
    yhrt <- function(t) sin(t) - sin(n*t)

    dat$y=yhrt(dat$t)
    dat$x=xhrt(dat$t)

    plot(
        dat$x,dat$y, type="l",xlab="",ylab="",
        main = paste("n =",  n, sep=" ")
        # main = expression(paste("n =",  n, sep=" "))
    )

    grid()

}

mydraw(2)
mydraw(1/3,-10,10)
```

An illustration:
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mydraw <- function(n,lb=-pi,up= pi){

  dat<- data.frame(t=seq(lb,up, by=0.001) )

  xhrt <- function(t) cos(t) - cos(n*t)
  yhrt <- function(t) sin(t) - sin(n*t)

  dat$y=yhrt(dat$t)
  dat$x=xhrt(dat$t)

  # Check if n is an integer
  if(n%%1){
    f <- strsplit(attributes(MASS::fractions(n))$fracs, split = "/")
    MyTitle <- bquote(n==frac(.(f[[1]][1]), .(f[[1]][2])))
  }else{
    MyTitle <- bquote(n==.(n))
  }

  plot(
    dat$x,dat$y, type="l",xlab="",ylab="",
    main = MyTitle
  )

  grid()
}

mydraw(2)
mydraw(1/3,-10,10)
```

Here, I first check to see if `n` is an integer or not. If not, I use `MASS::fractions` to turn `n` into a fraction, then I split the string at `/` and use the two parts in `frac` (from `grDevices`) to render the fraction. I'm not sure if it's the best solution, but it seems to work.

[image]

[image]